# TeeChart Axis ClearType fonts, how?

Tags: teechart

I`m trying to migrate from Delphi XE with TeeChart 8 to Delphi XE3 with TeeChart 2013. All is OK except one thing, there are no Clear type in axis font. Adding something like this:

```
    Chart.LeftAxis.LabelsFont.Quality := fqClearType;
```

does nothing.

PS: charts are created at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This has been modified for the next version of TeeChart VCL but in the actual v2013.08, the Font Quality is forced to fqNormal when the Font Size is <10, because the antialias doesn't look nice with small fonts. So you can try incrementing the Font Size to see the effect.

Also, note TeeChart v2013 is the first to use GDI+ by default. If you want to set GDI back, you can use:

```
uses TeCanvas;
//...
  Chart1.Canvas:=TTeeCanvas3D.Create;
```